# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает свойство hover у ссылки

Tags: css, hover

Помогите, пожалуйста, с изменением цвета ссылки. В теории должно работать, а на практике - не хочет. Вот html код, в котором расположены ссылки:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
<span class="sitename">Name Of Site</span>
<span class="motto">Slogan of the site</span>
<nav>
    <a href="/">Main Page</a>
    <a href="/">Second Page</a>
    <a href="/">Third Page</a>
    <a href="/">Fourth Page</a>
    <a href="/">Fifth Page</a>
    <a href="/">Sixth Page</a>
</nav>
</header>

<hr>
<main></main>  
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот свойства CSS для ссылок внутри тега nav:

```
nav a {
padding: 0 0.5rem;
font-size: 1.9rem;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
color: #CE242B;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a, nav a:visited {
color: #134799;
}
```

Вроде всё верно, но цвет ссылок неизменный :( Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас стиль для `nav a:visited` стоит ниже чем для `nav a:hover`, а так как специфичность у них одинаковая, то получается, что visited-цвет всегда побеждает

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, заработало, когда поменял hover и visited местами. Два часа мучался :) Честно говоря, очень неожиданный эффект - я полагал, что это абсолютно разные свойства. Получается, если я их поменял местами, то свойство hover "затрёт" visited? Как тогда можно правильно задавать эти свойства, если одно из них отменяет иное?

Comment: Ничто не мешает ссылке быть hover и visited одновременно (собственно, достаточно навести курсор мыши на посещённую ссылку и вот), ну а когда оба свойства активны одновременно, то побеждают те стили, у которых приоритет выше

Comment: @andreymal понял вас, огромное спасибо за ответы :) Буду читать про приоритеты этих свойств.